# Android toolbar height difference

Tags: android, height, size, material-design, toolbar

recently I started working with android toolbars. 
I am testing on android version 4.4.4 and 5.1.1. I am facing that the toolbars height are different. I have been trying hard to find an answer with no luck. I can provide source code, if you need.

Thanks in advance and Happy Holidays!

[image]

Comment: add your source code.

Comment: Forgot to add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your layout by any chance?

Comment: I think, I forgot to add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`. Thank you @MH.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already recreated the project from scratch, so I can not provide source code. Maybe I forgot to add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in my layout.xml.