# Maintain Android Toolbar height with app:elevation="0dp"

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I'm newbie in Android so this might be the easy question for you guys but I'm stuck. I want to remove shadow of `Toolbar` so I followed thread [how to remove shadow below actionbar with AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491667/how-to-remove-shadow-below-actionbar-with-appcompat-light-noactionbar) and using `app:elevation="0dp"` I was able to remove the shadow of `Toolbar` but that change the current height of `Toolbar` as displayed in [Image 2]. I want maintain the same exact size of `Toolbar` but without shadow. I also used `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from thread [Android toolbar height difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34462832/android-toolbar-height-difference) but it move `Profile` text on top and also create white line at bottom [Image 3] .

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

I guess we can use `android:layout_height:Xdp` or `android:layout_height:Xpx` but is this the last option or there is default way to do this.

Comment: try using 60dp and let me know

Comment: https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar

Comment: Post the whole XML..